# Treat binary files as a hex string

Tags: git, hex

Is there a way to configure git in a way, that it will treat binary files like a text file containing hexadecimal string? I'd like to be able to compare files between commits in a similar way as I can in any hex viewer (e.g. Notepad++ with Hex Editor plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom `textconv` attribute for your binary files.  The [`gitattributes` manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) suggests a sample filter for PNG images to allow them to meaningfully diff'd.  To diff arbitrary `*.bin` files, I'd recommend a gitattributes entry similar to the following:

```
[diff "bin"]
    textconv = xxd
    cachetextconv = true
```

This would feed the file to `xxd`, a hex converter shipped with Vim.  You may need to pick a different (but similar) tool if you don't expect  your collaborators to have Vim installed.

Note that this strategy does *not* let you edit or merge the resulting text and have it reinterpreted by Git.  You would need a custom merge tool for that.